# Как найти файл конфига программы Audio Recorder

Tags: linux, файлы, config

Собственно, вопрос уже задан в заголовке. Пробовал искать в

```
/etc
/opt
/usr/share
```

Но так и не нашел. Название самого файла конфига не знаю. Пробовал уже просто искать везде по слову "audiorecorder","audio-recorder" и просто "audio", но опять же безрезультатно.

Comment: `strace -e trace=open /path/to/audiorecorder/binary`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Linux User Config  /home/NAMEUSER/.config
```

Самое неожиданное место:) Его надо изначально проверять! А лучше создайте еще одного пользователя и проверьте повторяется ли там эта ситуация. Если не повторяется то ищите в этой директории.

**Dconf:**

dconf – низкоуровневая система конфигурации, система конфигурации основанная на ключах, при помощи которой в GNOME, MATE и Unity хранятся настройки большинства приложений. Ключи конфигурации находятся в неструктурированной базе данных (ключи логически связанные между собой объединены в категории), база данных ключей хранится в бинарном файле, который располагается:

```
~/.config/dconf
```

Редактировать можно через GUI с помощью программы `dconf-editor` (яб использовал версию dconf-editor-3.20-3.20.3-1 , а то после реформ gnome удобства работы упали...)

**Dconf бэкапы:**

Как бэкапить(сохранять настройки в файл)?

```
dconf dump /org/gnome/terminal/ > terminal-backup
```

*(Создаст бэкап настроек определенных в terminal-backup)*

Как восстановить настройки из файла? Обратная функция

```
dconf load /org/gnome/terminal/ < terminal-backup
```

Вы без труда сможете перенести определенные настройки на другую систему. Если требуются все настройки перенести, я описал выше какой файл надо переносить ( ~/.config/dconf ) (~ это папка пользователя)

**Debug:**

```
strace -e trace=open /путь к утилите
```

Что такое strace? Системная утилита помогающяя продебагить прогу. В данном случае отображает **ОТКРЫТЫЕ** прогой дескрипторы(файлики там..., сокеты). Обычные пути "/usr/bin/audio..." или "/usr/sbin/audio..."  (можно узнать из echo $PATH , если оно открывается из терминала)

**В чем изначально ошиблись?**

```
/usr
```

В этом каталоге хранятся все **установленные пакеты программ, документация, исходный код ядра и система X Window**. Все пользователи кроме суперпользователя root имеют доступ только для чтения. Может быть смонтирована по сети и может быть общей для нескольких машин.

```
/opt
```

Директория, в которой обычно **размещаются установленные программы**, имеющие большой дисковый размер или вспомогательные пакеты (например /opt/openoffice.org).

```
/etc
```

В этой директории находится **основная часть конфигурационных файлов самой операционной системы** (настройки сети, список пользователей, групп и т.д.) и различных программ (Apache, Samba и т. д.).

Comment: Благодарю. Сначала испугался 32-х листов лога, но потом понял, что достаточно сохранить настройки и посмотреть какие строчки появятся.  Было открыто 2 файла:  
open("/run/user/1000/dconf/user", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0600) = 26
open("/home/hepoh/.config/dconf/user", O_RDONLY) = 26
Судя по O_RDONLY, последний файл открыт только для чтения, и конфигом является первый. Но он двоичный, смогу ли я править его под свои нужды, или можно, скажем скопировать его на в другую систему и настройки перенесутся?

Comment: Я посмотрел что это за /run/user/1000/dconf/user . Возможно это сокет. Но точно именно к вашей проге отношения не имеет.  ААА dconf. о чем я думаю... щяс допишу описание...

Comment: Я забыл об этом) Я понел что вы хотите перенести систему? Вам достаточно перенести полностью home. С помощью cp -a .../* куда

Comment: Вам поможет dconf-editor для редактирования настроект прог. Dconf напоминает реестр винды, принцып тотже.

Comment: Не совсем, мне нужно не перенести систему. Мне нужно настроить гуишное приложение на устройстве без дисплея. Либо настроить его у себя и скинуть конфиг на то устройтсво.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку о dconf-editod, там действительно можно настроить приложение. Проблема только в том, что он тоже гуишный. Можно ли из него как-то экспортировать настройки конкретного приложения (если он похож на реестр винды). Судя по всему, из терминала ключи можно поменять при помощи gsettings.

Comment: Описал как это делается через dconf. А так да можно через gsettings работать, но зачем когда есть готовые для этого способы.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62521/discussion-between---and--).